# Problem with padding on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to make a responsive website (Desktop, Tablet, and Smartphone), and I would like to show it in different browsers.

This is how I built my `links` with **nav-element** on my html site:

```
<nav id="navs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/es/about_us.php">Nosotros</a></li>
    <li><a href="/es/contact.php">Contactar</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="/es/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Linux OS</a>
       <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="/es/linux_mint.php">Linux Mint</a>
         <a href="/es/ubuntu.php">Ubuntu</a>
         <a href="/es/debian.php">Debian</a>
         <a href="/es/android.php">Android</a>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="new-link">
      <a href="#" class="neuen">News & Mas</a>
      <div class="new-content">
       <a href="#">News</a>
       <a href="#">Geek</a>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li><a id="book" href="#">Libros</a></li>
   <li class="languag">
    <a href="#" class="language">&#127757; Ingles</a>
    <div class="languages">
     <a href="https://linuxusers.net">Ingles</a>
     <a href="https://linuxusers.net/de/index.php">Aleman</a>
    </div>
   </li> 
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In my CSS file I give the class **dropdown-content** these parameters:

```
.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 17px;
}
```

Image from **Firefox**, highlighted in the red box the class `.dropdown-content a`

[image: image from Firefoy]

Image from **Chrome**, highlighted in the red box the class `.dropdown-content a`

[image: image from Chrome]

How is it possible that the image shown on Chrome is smaller than the one shown in Firefox?

[This](https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/xxxbERq) is my HTML and CSS code.

I have searched similar questions on **stackexchange**, but the solutions provided didn't working for me.

Can someone help me to solve this problem, please?

Comment: biotza -- Does adding `display: block;` to your CSS for the `.dropdown-content a` element make both lists look the same? I'm wondering if the difference you're seeing is from the browsers treating the padding around inline elements differently. If that doesn't fix it, it may help to see more of the CSS for your menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! , I to doing with display: block; but nothing to change, I will now new edit ma question and give more information...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2KPHrmW On macOS, I'm seeing less than a pixel's width of difference between Chrome and Firefox. It's possible a typography setting may correct for that, but it's probably not worth chasing down. Maybe try adding normalize.css or a reset to your project?

Comment: very thanks for your support! , Tomorrow I will to try it, with normalize.css , i wish your a nice Night !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem!

How [Angelique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtiTF.jpg) to tell, there are less than a pixel's (0.8333) width of difference between Chrome and Firefox, I am with Linux, she is with Mac and are not difference...

For **Firefox** I to give for **padding** these parameters:

```
.dropdown-content a {
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 12px 17px;
}
```

For building the **padding** parameters for **Chrome** I use [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) + **padding** and give the number 16, I give only the second Place because, on **padding**, the Second Place is to move to right Site.., how to show it,

```
.dropdown-content a {

   -webkit-padding-start: 16px;
}
```

and now I have both (Firefox and Chrome) with identical big...

Very Thanks to **Angelique** because you help me to Understand it and **Adriano** for correct my English, I wish all your a nice Week!